# Another metric with the same name already exists

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I have problem with this code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
```

and got this errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "K:\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
  File "G:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\api\_v2\keras\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from keras import __version__
  File "G:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from keras import models
  File "G:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py", line 20, in <module>
    from keras import metrics as metrics_module
  File "G:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\metrics.py", line 26, in <module>
    from keras import activations
  File "G:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\activations.py", line 20, in <module>
    from keras.layers import advanced_activations
  File "G:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from keras.engine.input_layer import Input
  File "G:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\input_layer.py", line 21, in <module>
    from keras.engine import base_layer
  File "G:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 43, in <module>
    from keras.mixed_precision import loss_scale_optimizer
  File "G:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\mixed_precision\loss_scale_optimizer.py", line 18, in <module>
    from keras import optimizers
  File "G:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\optimizers.py", line 26, in <module>
    from keras.optimizer_v2 import adadelta as adadelta_v2
  File "G:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\optimizer_v2\adadelta.py", line 22, in <module>
    from keras.optimizer_v2 import optimizer_v2
  File "G:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\optimizer_v2\optimizer_v2.py", line 37, in <module>
    "/tensorflow/api/keras/optimizers", "keras optimizer usage", "method")
  File "G:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\monitoring.py", line 361, in __init__
    len(labels), name, description, *labels)
  File "G:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\monitoring.py", line 135, in __init__
    self._metric = self._metric_methods[self._label_length].create(*args)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.AlreadyExistsError: Another metric with the same name already exists
```

I have seen
[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58012741/error-importing-tensorflow-alreadyexistserror-another-metric-with-the-same-nam/68970617#68970617)
and didn't get the meaning of

> never import twice

Comment: Your single line of code that you posted is not enough to give you any feedback.
Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: "Importing twice" means that you open the python interpreter, and then run the `from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential` twice.

Comment: where is twice importing? just one line and occurred an error

Comment: That's the entire script? That single line? If yes, then I'm sure that the error lies elsewhere, because that single line sounds like it should work ... I can double-check, though

Comment: it's just a single line, without anything

Comment: Then we need more information about your setup, because this command works for me and does not throw the error you are describing:
`python -c "from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential"` (Running on Python 3.9.6, Windows 10, Tensorflow/Keras 2.6.0)

Comment: it has a same error, :  
self._metric = self._metric_methods[self._label_length].create(*args)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.AlreadyExistsError: Another metric with the same name already exists.

Comment: Again, as long as I can't reproduce your problem, I can't help. We need more information about your Python/Tensorflow setup.

Comment: Hi , Can you please try same in a new virtual environment , As there might be multiple tensorflow installations in that environment. Also try with following command.         from tensorflow.keras import Sequential .

Answer (score 12):

you can fix the problem by downgrading Keras version to `2.6.0`,
Even you only installed TensorFlow, it installs Keras==2.7.1 as a partial dependency. Simply, this version difference causes the error.
In `IPython Kernel` or In an active environment,
`pip install keras==2.6.0`
In a deployment environment, like docker,
add `keras==2.6.0` line at the last line in the `requirements.txt`.

Comment: Just to clarify: after `pip install tensorflow==2.6.0`, keras==2.7.0 is installed. 
`pip install keras==2.6.0` works for me.

Interestingly, in tensorflow2.6 docker image, keras is 2.6.0.

Comment: thanks,  solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

Follow these three steps below:

1. `pip uninstall tensorflow`
2. delete all keras related files in PC directory:
   `\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages`
3. reinstall tensorflow

This has solved my problem.