# AlreadyExistsError: Another metric with the same name already exists. In colab

Tags: tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

I rerun my colab notebook after some time, and it threw an error on:

```
from object_detection.builders import model_builder
```

Which says:
`AlreadyExistsError: Another metric with the same name already exists.`

And this is also the case while importing keras:

```
import keras
```

How to pass through it and what are the reasons behind it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There might be two scenarios in this issue.

1. Either you might have opened a second program which is using Tensorflow library. In this case, You have to close the second program and check the status in first program.
2. You might be using TF 2.6 which is installing Keras 2.7 automatically.In this case, You can solve this issue by installing Keras 2.6 manually through pip installation.

Attaching Relevant threads for reference. [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58012741/error-importing-tensorflow-alreadyexistserror-another-metric-with-the-same-nam),[link2](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/52922),[link3](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/51592#issuecomment-960363675)